# Dataframe index date adding and appending list value

Tags: python, dataframe

Having a data frame as below:

[image: img]

The Date column is index column.I need to add a new date value and append a list value as volume.

`Volume=[39]`

This Volume value needs to be added to data frame.
So last value of index date+7 needs to be the first column
Expected output:

[image: output]

`Date Column is index column`

Can some one please help me?

Comment: Your question is unclear. We know new volume(39) but what is date ? Do you define date too?

Comment: @Bushmaster, Last date+7 Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use append, like so:

```
import datetime
# get the last row
last_date = yourDf.iloc[[-1]].index
formatted_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(last_date, "%m/%d/%y")

# add 7 days
end_date = formatted_date + datetime.timedelta(days=7)

# append data
data = {'Volume': 39}
yourDf.append(pd.DataFrame(data, index=[end_date]))
```